# Stop Android webview covering tabwidget

Tags: android, android-layout, tabwidget

I have a tabwidget placed at the bottom of the screen with a webview above it. When the content of the webpage the webview loads is larger than the screen, the webview expands to conver the tabwidget - because the layout_height is set to wrap_content in the webview and the scrollview it sits in.

I'd like the scrollview to size to the available screen space.
My xml is as follows:

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="0dp" >

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp"
        android:gravity="top" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroll1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            tools:ignore="UselessParent" >

            <WebView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/webView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:gravity="bottom"/>
        </ScrollView>

    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I've put in a set height for the scrollview but as would be expected it is only accurate to a certain device(s), not universal.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: For anyone having the same problem - I came back to this after a while and have solved it by simply adding an android:layout_marginBottom value to the scrollview.

Comment: Have you tried removing 
    tools:ignore="UselessParent"

Comment: I had that line omitted initially and it was giving me an error of sorts.

Answer (score 0):

use this xml , it will solve your problem :

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="0dp" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scroll1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                tools:ignore="UselessParent" >

                <WebView
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:id="@+id/webView1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="bottom" />
            </ScrollView>
        </FrameLayout>

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```